# A timeout has occurred while while invoking commands in SharePoint host process

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, iis, visual-studio-2012

My scenario: i am trying to deploy a SharePoint Addin to SharePoint 2016 but i receive the following error :  A timeout has occurred while while invoking commands in SharePoint host process.

I had a look at this [post](http://ukreddysharepoint2010.blogspot.com/2012/06/error-occured-in-deployment-step-add.html) but since am using visual studio 2017 i can't seem to find the registry key to add the timeout variable. I have also increase the timeout time on IIS manager for the application pool am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i found out where to really add that registry key. Note in my case SharePointTools registry didn't exist. I have created the latter manually.

This kind of key should be the same for any user. So it is stored in HKLM, not in HKCU. So the key is stored in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\SharePointTools.

Note the added Wow6432Node.

Add the following as a DWORD (won't be there by default)

ChannelOperationTimeout

Set its value to something more than 120(which is the default value). In my case 360 did the work